# What is the difference between the "WSH" and "WScript" objects?

Tags: wsh, windows-scripting

What is the difference between the `WSH` and `WScript` objects?

`this.wsf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
    <job id="this">
        <?job error="true" debug="true"?>
        <script>
            this;
            debugger;
        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

Double click on the WSF file, or execute this command to debug with Visual Studio:

```
wscript /d /x this.wsf
```

In Visual Studio, when you hover over `this`, you see two objects: `WSH` and `WScript`.

Which should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same object, so it doesn't matter which one you use, but all the examples use WScript.